# C++ libcurl Caching Data Response

Tags: caching, libcurl, protocol-buffers

I am using curl lib and easy_curl extension for this.
I am going to leave out code for now as i do not think it is necessary for explaining the issue. I am using c++ and curl lib in order to retrieve a serialized google prototype from a server. The serialized protobuff contains an integer and a static array of objects. The compiled protobuff looks like

```
typedef struct _ExperimentRunner_ExperimentList_RES {
    int32_t pollFrequency;
    pb_size_t activeExperiments_count;
    ExperimentRunner_ExperimentInfo activeExperiments[5];
/* @@protoc_insertion_point(struct:ExperimentRunner_ExperimentList_RES) */
} ExperimentRunner_ExperimentList_RES;
```

When tested everything works fine and the protobuff is retrieved from the server and parsed correctly. The get request is for data not a file from the server.

The code is setup in such a way that the experiment list is retrieved every poll frequency. The issue is the following scenario

1. app start and retrieves the experiment list, which currently
   has one entry
2. remove the entry from the server database wait for the
   app to re-poll the server
3. The app sees the server response still containing the entry that was removed. I confirm its removed by doing a curl from the command line

There seems to be an issue with the curl library caching the data result from the server, and then returning it when I make a request. since when I restart the application it gets the correct data. I have implemented CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION and see the old data being returned by the request when i know the server has it deleted from the database. Any suggestions what options or caching might be going on to cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a dump mistake by me caused by miss-understanding how curl lib works (i think). I was using CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to capture the data in a char array. I was not fully clearing this buff inbetween requests as I was assuming that curllib would terminate the new received data with a "\0", invalidating the old data. but I think this assumption is untrue. Once i cleared the entire buffer before the next req everything worked great. bellow is the data capture function for incase

```
size_t CURL_RECIEVE_DATA_BUFF(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    CURL_DATA_BUFF* curlData = (CURL_DATA_BUFF*)userp;
    if (curlData)
    {
        if (curlData->amountWriten >= curlData->maxSize) {
            LogIt.Add(Error, "%s:%s Server sending more data than expected, max is: %d bytes\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, curlData->maxSize);
            return 0;
        }
        memcpy(&(curlData->buff[curlData->amountWriten]), buffer, size * nmemb);
        curlData->amountWriten += size * nmemb;
        return size * nmemb;
    }
    return 0;
}
```